# Invalid CEN header (bad entry name) in Stata

Tags: stata, unzip

I'm trying to download and unzip files into Stata. This is the do file I've written:

```
cd "path"
local mods "737 687 634 603 546 498"
foreach var of local mods {
copy "http://iinei.inei.gob.pe/iinei/srienaho/descarga/STATA/`var'-Modulo01.zip" ///
"Modulo_`var'.zip", replace
unzipfile "Modulo_`var'.zip"
erase "Modulo_`var'.zip"
}
```

The code downloads the files, but doesn't unzip them and gives me this error:
"invalid CEN header (bad entry name)"

I'm using Stata 17.

Comment: Frankly, I have a zero risk policy in opening files like this, and others may agree. A  simple question: is it true?  Have you tested the files using any other unzipping software?

Comment: Yes, I can unzip the files using winrar and 7zip, by the way, the files are from the National institute of statistics of Perú (a government site), so they aren’t malicious.

Comment: What are the sizes of these files? CEN header errors seems to be common with big files. Since there are only 6 files, would downloading those files manually and then reading them from disk be an acceptable solution if that works?

Answer (score -1):

Just add capture before unzipfile.

```
capture unzipfile "Modulo_`var'.zip"
```

Comment: This fixes nothing if the zip file is problematic.

Comment: This will make the code run, but as Nick says unlikely to solve any error. `capture` is very error prone to use unless the `_rc` return codes are handles as it suppresses errors. Countless of times have I reviewed code with significant errors due to using `capture` as a quick fix like this.

Comment: I understand your position on the matter. What solution do you propose? STATA should have had a Spanish version for a long time so that it can recognize special characters.